# Rendering GET request response in HTML file

Tags: html, http, go, rendering

I have just started learning REST APIs in Go and I cannot figure out how to display the response of the GET request in my HTML file.
What I basically did is create a function `GetCurrency()` which gets data from a third-party API. Now I'm trying to render the response `Currency` in an HTML file but I don't seem to get it right as whenever the localhost loads `/getcurrency` I get a blank page although my `.gohtml` file contains a form.

Here is my struct in the main.go file

```
type pageData struct {
    Title    string
    Currency string
}
```

Here is my main function in the main.go file

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", home)
    http.HandleFunc("/home", home)
    http.HandleFunc("/getcurrency", getCurrency)
    http.ListenAndServe(":5050", nil)
}
```

and here is my `home` function where the HTML is executed

```
func home(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    pd := pageData{
        Title: "Etmazec Home Page",
    }

    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "homepage.gohtml", pd)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, "Internal server error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

and here is my `getCurrency()` function in the `main.go` file

```
func getCurrency(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    pd := pageData{
        Title: "Welcome to the exchange rate website",
    }
    err := tpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "currency.gohtml", pd)
    response, err := http.Get("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/spot?currency=USD")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("The http requst failed with error %s \n", err)
    } else {
        data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
        pd.Currency = string(data)
        fmt.Println(string(data))
    }
}
```

Finally, here is my `currency.gohtml` body

```
<body>
    <h1>TOP HITS</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/home">HOME PAGE</a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <form action="/getcurrency" method="GET">
        <label for="fname">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    {{.Currency}}
      </body>
```

and here is my `home.gohtml` file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/main.css">
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>

    <h1>Currency HomePage</h1>

    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/home">HOME PAGE</a>
            <li><a href="/getcurrency">The Currency</a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: You have a Go template. Where / how are you executing it?

Comment: @icza I use git bash inside the project folder and type `go run main.go`

Comment: You posted an HTML template, what's inside your `.gohtml` file. That is the source of an unprocessed template. You have to read it, parse it, and execute it to generate an actual HTML code. Where / how do you do it? The code you posted doesn't do that. Please try to come up with a [mcve].

Comment: inside `main.go`
I have the following function since my `.gohtml` file is inside a folder called templates
`func init() {
 tpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.gohtml"))
}`

Comment: That's the reading and parsing part. Where do you execute it? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @icza Done, just edited my question

Comment: Your `getCurrency()` function doesn't write anything to its output (`w`), so you seeing a blank page seems about right. You have to send a response HTML document that will be displayed. If you want to embed the response, you can't use a form POST like that, you need to execute an AJAX call then.

Comment: @icza Alright, i figured out that i was missing the HTML execution part in the `getCurrency()` method. However, I am still not getting the response data displayed although I am rending `{{.Currency}}` after the form in the `.gohtml` file which means that below the form i should get the response

Comment: Please post how you execute now the template in `getCurrency()`.

Comment: @icza Done, updated my ques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fmt.Println(string(data))` from func getCurrency() prints into standard output. So you see resulting HTML in app console but it is not returned to browser.

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println:

> Println formats using the default formats for its operands and writes
>   to standard output.

You need to send your bytes into `w http.ResponseWriter` handler argument:

```
fmt.Fprintln(w, string(data))
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintln

Comment: What if i want to print a specific data inside the response reterived and not the whole response?

Comment: @MarwaA. Did not get you question. Normally you write into `w` and return immediately for every code branch that assumes end of request due to error or successful execution.

Comment: i mean using `fmt.Fprintln(w, string(data))` i get the following  `{"data":{"base":"BTC","currency":"USD","amount":"4225.87"}}`. Now what if i want to get `USD` only

Comment: https://gobyexample.com/json You need to create new struct type for your request and Unmarshal response bytes into it.

Comment: I have tried the following lines of code

`answer, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
  var data map[string]interface{}
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(answer), &data)
  if err != nil {
   panic(err)
  }
  fmt.Fprintln(w, data["currency"])`

but it doesnt show anything

Comment: You cannot Unmarshal random JSON to `map`.  Create new struct type for your request. Link that I gave you contains sample.

Comment: I created the following struct `type money struct {
 Base     string  `json:"base"`
 Currency string  `json:"currency"`
 Amount   float32 `json:"amount"`
}
`

and wrote the following code and  still It doesnt work (nothing gets displayed)
`answer, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

  res := money{}
  json.Unmarshal([]byte(answer), &res)
  fmt.Println(res)
  fmt.Println(res.Currency)`